# Why is saveAsTextFile hanging when I try to output an RDD to HDFS?

Tags: apache-spark, hdfs, rdd

I'm trying to write an RDD[String] to HDFS (in spark-shell) using:

```
output.saveAsTextFile("hdfs://localhost:9000/datasets/result")
```

However, it just hangs - and the job doesn't even appear in the web UI. I have to kill the SparkSubmit process.

I'm reading data successful from HDFS using:

```
val input = sc.textFile("hdfs://localhost:9000/datasets/data.csv")
```

I can `output.collect` successfully, and writing to local files works as expected.

I'm using Spark 1.4 and Hadoop 2.6. Everything is running on a local machine.

Any ideas?

Comments made me realize that, I should switch on DEBUG level logs. Initial log extract below. There's something about the connection being closed. But, I read the data from HDFS at the start of the short script, so I'm confused.

### Solution (kind of)

Must be something to do with local routing. I replaced localhost with 127.0.0.1 and it's working now.

### Debug logs

```
15/06/30 17:04:42 DEBUG ClosureCleaner: +++ Cleaning closure <function1> (org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$saveAsTextFile$1$$anonfun$30}) +++
15/06/30 17:04:42 DEBUG ClosureCleaner:  + declared fields: 1
15/06/30 17:04:42 DEBUG ClosureCleaner:      public static final long org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$saveAsTextFile$1$$anonfun$30.serialVersionUID
15/06/30 17:04:42 DEBUG ClosureCleaner:  + declared methods: 2
15/06/30 17:04:42 DEBUG ClosureCleaner:      public final java.lang.Object org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$saveAsTextFile$1$$anonfun$30.apply(java.lang.Object)
15/06/30 17:04:42 DEBUG ClosureCleaner:      public final scala.collection.Iterator org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$saveAsTextFile$1$$anonfun$30.apply(scala.collection.Iterator)
15/06/30 17:04:42 DEBUG ClosureCleaner:  + inner classes: 1
15/06/30 17:04:42 DEBUG ClosureCleaner:      org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$saveAsTextFile$1$$anonfun$30$$anonfun$apply$49
15/06/30 17:04:42 DEBUG ClosureCleaner:  + outer classes: 0
15/06/30 17:04:42 DEBUG ClosureCleaner:  + outer objects: 0
15/06/30 17:04:42 DEBUG ClosureCleaner:  + populating accessed fields because this is the starting closure
15/06/30 17:04:42 DEBUG ClosureCleaner:  + fields accessed by starting closure: 0
15/06/30 17:04:42 DEBUG ClosureCleaner:  + there are no enclosing objects!
15/06/30 17:04:42 DEBUG ClosureCleaner:  +++ closure <function1> (org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$saveAsTextFile$1$$anonfun$30) is now cleaned +++
15/06/30 17:04:42 DEBUG BlockReaderLocal: dfs.client.use.legacy.blockreader.local = false
15/06/30 17:04:42 DEBUG BlockReaderLocal: dfs.client.read.shortcircuit = false
15/06/30 17:04:42 DEBUG BlockReaderLocal: dfs.client.domain.socket.data.traffic = false
15/06/30 17:04:42 DEBUG BlockReaderLocal: dfs.domain.socket.path = 
15/06/30 17:04:42 DEBUG DFSClient: No KeyProvider found.
15/06/30 17:04:43 DEBUG Client: IPC Client (832019786) connection to localhost/127.0.0.1:9000 from user: closed
15/06/30 17:04:43 DEBUG Client: IPC Client (832019786) connection to localhost/127.0.0.1:9000 from user: stopped, remaining connections 0
15/06/30 17:04:48 DEBUG AkkaRpcEnv$$anonfun$actorRef$lzycompute$1$1$$anon$1: [actor] received message AkkaMessage(Heartbeat(driver,[Lscala.Tuple2;@4eb1e256,BlockManagerId(driver, localhost, 51349)),true) from Actor[akka://sparkDriver/temp/$L]
15/06/30 17:04:48 DEBUG AkkaRpcEnv$$anonfun$actorRef$lzycompute$1$1$$anon$1: Received RPC message: AkkaMessage(Heartbeat(driver,[Lscala.Tuple2;@4eb1e256,BlockManagerId(driver, localhost, 51349)),true)
15/06/30 17:04:48 DEBUG AkkaRpcEnv$$anonfun$actorRef$lzycompute$1$1$$anon$1: [actor] handled message (0.290877 ms) AkkaMessage(Heartbeat(driver,[Lscala.Tuple2;@4eb1e256,BlockManagerId(driver, localhost, 51349)),true) from Actor[akka://sparkDriver/temp/$L]
15/06/30 17:04:48 DEBUG AkkaRpcEnv$$anonfun$actorRef$lzycompute$1$1$$anon$1: [actor] received message AkkaMessage(BlockManagerHeartbeat(BlockManagerId(driver, localhost, 51349)),true) from Actor[akka://sparkDriver/temp/$M]
15/06/30 17:04:48 DEBUG AkkaRpcEnv$$anonfun$actorRef$lzycompute$1$1$$anon$1: Received RPC message: AkkaMessage(BlockManagerHeartbeat(BlockManagerId(driver, localhost, 51349)),true)
15/06/30 17:04:48 DEBUG AkkaRpcEnv$$anonfun$actorRef$lzycompute$1$1$$anon$1: [actor] handled message (0.257991 ms) AkkaMessage(BlockManagerHeartbeat(BlockManagerId(driver, localhost, 51349)),true) from Actor[akka://sparkDriver/temp/$M]
15/06/30 17:04:57 DEBUG RetryUtils: multipleLinearRandomRetry = null
15/06/30 17:04:57 DEBUG Client: getting client out of cache: org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client@7d1fc150
15/06/30 17:04:57 DEBUG DataTransferSaslUtil: DataTransferProtocol not using SaslPropertiesResolver, no QOP found in configuration for dfs.data.transfer.protection
15/06/30 17:04:57 DEBUG PairRDDFunctions: Saving as hadoop file of type (NullWritable, Text)
15/06/30 17:04:57 DEBUG Client: The ping interval is 60000 ms.
15/06/30 17:04:57 DEBUG Client: Connecting to localhost/81.200.64.50:9000
15/06/30 17:04:58 DEBUG AkkaRpcEnv$$anonfun$actorRef$lzycompute$1$1$$anon$1: [actor] received message AkkaMessage(Heartbeat(driver,[Lscala.Tuple2;@7aba4180,BlockManagerId(driver, localhost, 51349)),true) from Actor[akka://sparkDriver/temp/$N]
15/06/30 17:04:58 DEBUG AkkaRpcEnv$$anonfun$actorRef$lzycompute$1$1$$anon$1: Received RPC message: AkkaMessage(Heartbeat(driver,[Lscala.Tuple2;@7aba4180,BlockManagerId(driver, localhost, 51349)),true)
15/06/30 17:04:58 DEBUG AkkaRpcEnv$$anonfun$actorRef$lzycompute$1$1$$anon$1: [actor] handled message (0.277965 ms) AkkaMessage(Heartbeat(driver,[Lscala.Tuple2;@7aba4180,BlockManagerId(driver, localhost, 51349)),true) from Actor[akka://sparkDriver/temp/$N]
15/06/30 17:04:58 DEBUG AkkaRpcEnv$$anonfun$actorRef$lzycompute$1$1$$anon$1: [actor] received message AkkaMessage(BlockManagerHeartbeat(BlockManagerId(driver, localhost, 51349)),true) from Actor[akka://sparkDriver/temp/$O]
15/06/30 17:04:58 DEBUG AkkaRpcEnv$$anonfun$actorRef$lzycompute$1$1$$anon$1: Received RPC message: AkkaMessage(BlockManagerHeartbeat(BlockManagerId(driver, localhost, 51349)),true)
15/06/30 17:04:58 DEBUG AkkaRpcEnv$$anonfun$actorRef$lzycompute$1$1$$anon$1: [actor] handled message (0.258037 ms) AkkaMessage(BlockManagerHeartbeat(BlockManagerId(driver, localhost, 51349)),true) from Actor[akka://sparkDriver/temp/$O]
```

Comment: Can you post your logs?

Comment: Did you check the spark stderr or stdout logs, what they say? Do you have enough disk space? I'd like to suggest you just put a file to HDFS to see if the problems in HDFS, such as: hdfs dfs -put test.txt hdfs://localhost:9000/

Comment: I'm having no problem moving files in and out of HDFS. I put the original dataset on to parse it. Space isn't an issue. I've got one file on it.

Comment: As for logs. I'm logging to the console, but nothing appears when I execute the saveAsTextFile function. Are there other logs I need to investigate? If so, where would I find them?

Comment: I enabled DEBUG logging. Extract attached.

Comment: Any news? how did resolve this issue?

Comment: See above: "Must be something to do with local routing. I replaced localhost with 127.0.0.1 and it's working now."